# Geometry problem: relation between side of an equilateral triangle and that of a regular heptagon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need to prove that half the side of an equilateral triangle inscribed circle differs from side of a regular inscribed heptagon by less than $\dfrac{1}{500}$ of the radius.

I am stuck and couldn't find the value of $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{7}$.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use calculator, you may approximate $\cos \frac{\pi}{7}$ by known trigonometric function values. As you always can find $\cos \frac {\pi}{2^k}$, you may approximate $\frac{\pi}{7}$ as $\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi}{64} < \frac{\pi}{7} < \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi}{32}$ or even more precise to get the accuracy you need.